# Referencing a custom external javascript file in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm trying to pull some javascript on a page off of the page and putting it into an external javascript file for reusability.

Just as a test I'm just trying to display an alert text box but even that's not working.

Here's what I have so far.

Page with the javascript

EDIT: Ignore the type="text/javascript" that wasn't the problem

[image]

Here's the actual content of the script.js

[image]

File Structure from the site root

[image]

Honestly it looks like it should work but whenever I run the page in the browser I'm getting this error.

[image]

I know that the path is correct, but what am I missing?

Comment: Can you make sure you can see the script.js file in Firebug and that the contents are what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't clearing my cache, sorry newbie mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some simple javascript syntax errors; missing semicolons. You can use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to find those. This should work (Assuming that jQuery is loading before your other two scripts):

Your 'script.js':

```
var projectApi = function() {};

projectApi.prototype.HelloWorld = function() {
    alert('Hello World');
};
```

Your page javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var api = new projectApi();
    api.HelloWorld();
});
```